# make all wrap (text img) decrease left to right

Tags: jquery

How to make the all wrap after click left to right decrease the size become not visible?
now I use width 0 for div and img but can't find the way make same effect on text, also if use opacity it will flash after finish

```
$('.wrap').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        width: '0'
    });
    $(this).find('.back').animate({
    width: '0'
    });

    $(this).find('.text').animate({
    opacity: '0'
    });
});

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="text"><div class="title">背後的故事</div></div>
    <div class="back"><img src="../public/imgs/2/back.png"></div>
</div>



.text{
    widht: 95px;
    height: 760px;
    position: absolute;
    .title{ 
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 95px;
        z-index: 1;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
}


.back{
    position: absolute;
    width: 97px;
    height: 760px;
    img{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: 90px;
        height: 600px;
        margin-left:-45px;
        margin-top: -300px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can animate the `font-size` property to change the size of the text. You should also animate the `.title` element rather than the `.text` element because you already have a font-size specified for `.title` in the CSS.

```
$('.wrap').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        width: '0'
    });
    $(this).find('.back').animate({
        width: '0'
    });
    $(this).find('.text .title').animate({ // Select the .title element here.
        'font-size': '0' // Animate font-size here. Make sure you use quotes.
    });
});
```

(Be sure to use the quotes around 'font-size' to make it a proper JavaScript object.)

Comment: Ah, you may need to apply the animation to the ".title" element instead. Answer is edited.